# Update Excel file using C# and OLEDB - Network file issue

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I don't have a lot of experience using C# to work with Excel.  I've had to google a lot of the techniques but have had pretty good luck.  What leads me here is a problem I'm having when trying to upgrade an Excel file on my company's network.  I don't have any trouble upgrading an Excel file on a local drive but when it is directed to a file on the network it fails with "The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object '\\nas1\eng\legacy\XView_Results\Book1-xview-test.xlsx'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly."

I've tried to change the path string to have four slashes and two slashes.
"\\nas1\eng\legacy\XView_Results\Book1-xview-test.xlsx"
but it fails, interpretted as:
\\nas1\eng\legacy\XView_Results\Book1-xview-test.xlsx
(Note: stackoverflow won't show my four & two slashes)

I've tried to use the C# technique with @
string FileName = @"\nas1\eng\legacy\XView_Results\Book1-xview-test.xlsx";
and changed the command to read:
MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
But get this error:
'\nas1\eng\legacy\XView_Results\Book1-xview-test.xlsx' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here's the code for the routine that is failing:

```
  private void buttonSendToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //try
        //{
            string FileName = @"\\nas1\eng\legacy\XView_Results\Book1-xview-test.xlsx";
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            string sql = null;
            string sql2 = null;
            string sql3 = null;
            //MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='\\\\nas1\\eng\\legacy\\XView_Results\\Book1-xview-test.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
            //MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\Book1-xview-test.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';");
            //MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='\\\nas1\\eng\\legacy\\XView_Results\\Book1-xview-test.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
            MyConnection.Open();
            myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

            sql = "Update [Sheet1$] set result=" + od + " where id=1";
            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sql2 = "Update [Sheet1$] set result=" + id + " where id=2";
            myCommand.CommandText = sql2;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sql3 = "Update [Sheet1$] set result=" + yield + " where id=3";
            myCommand.CommandText = sql3;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MyConnection.Close();
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        //}
    }
```

Comment: Can you make a local copy of the excel file, and run your code there.  And if that works..you know it is solely a network issue.

Comment: Yes, I had mentioned that it works fine on my local drive but fails on the network.

Comment: I like using `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` to help build my connection strings. It helps reduce syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks @S.Ahn, I'm looking at it.  I noticed in one of the examples that the network is being referred to with an IP address!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two things that were changed in my code to solve my problem.
1. Switched path to mapped mode, i.e., \server\file mapped to H:\file
2. Removed the component IMEX=1; from MyConnection

Here's the fixed code:

```
        try
        {            
            //string FileName = @"\\tiwnas1\eng\legacy\XView_Results\Book1-xview-test.xlsx";
            //string theFile = GetPath(@"\\tiwnas1\eng\legacy\Book1-xview-test_v8.xls");
            //string FileName = @"\\tiwnas1\eng\legacy\Book1-xview-test_v8.xls";

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            string sql = null;
            string sql2 = null;
            string sql3 = null;
            //MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
            //MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='\\\\tiwnas1\\eng\\legacy\\XView_Results\\Book1-xview-test.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
            //MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\Book1-xview-test.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';");
            //MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='\\tiwnas1\eng\legacy\XView_Results\Book1-xview-test.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
            //MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='H:\\Book1-xview-test_v8.xls';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
            //MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='h:\\Book1-xview-test_v8.xls';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='h:\\Book1-xview-test_v8.xls';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';");
            //MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + FileName + "';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
            MyConnection.Open();
            myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

            //sql = "Update [Sheet1$] set result=5.625 where id=1";
            sql = "Update [Sheet1$] set result=" + od + " where id=1";
            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //sql2 = "Update [Sheet1$] set result=5.375 where id=2";
            sql2 = "Update [Sheet1$] set result=" + id + " where id=2";
            myCommand.CommandText = sql2;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //sql3 = "Update [Sheet1$] set result=110000 where id=3";
            sql3 = "Update [Sheet1$] set result=" + yield + " where id=3";
            myCommand.CommandText = sql3;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MyConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a super slashed up path.

```
"\\\\Server\\MyNetworkDrive\\FolderOne\\FolderTwo\\MySuperCoolFile.xlsx"


@"\nas1\eng\legacy\XView_Results\Book1-xview-test.xlsx";
```

SHould that be?

```
@"\\nas1\eng\legacy\XView_Results\Book1-xview-test.xlsx";
```

Other Idea.

Put single quotes around the file name.  I actually put single quotes around every "value"..to be consistent.

example:

(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + FileName + "';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");

Note the single quote include to wrap the value of "FileName".

Comment: I thought the same thing and tried it that way and it still failed.  Oddly, the error message showed the path with three slashes and one slash: "\\\server\mynet\folder1\folder2\coolfile.xlsx". Still scratching my head! See the first commented out MyConnection.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read more carefully.  I made an edit to my response, about the "@" thing.

Comment: that's ok @granadaCoder.

Comment: Check my single quote hint, that I just added to my answer.

Comment: I thought your idea made sense so I tried it.  Unfortunately it failed.  Here's the error message:  '\\nas1\eng\legacy\XView_Results\Book1-xview-test.xlsx' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.  I've checked spelling and validity of path and it should have worked!

Comment: The file isn't read-only on the network, is it?  (sanity check).

Comment: The file is ready for archiving not read-only.  So should be fine.

Comment: I think I've stumbled on a fix.  All the suggestions you made were reasonable and should have fixed the problem. I went back to the mapped mode and saw that \\nas1\eng\legacy mapped to h:, so I changed the path to that.  That was accepted and moved into the sql section where it failed with "Operation must use an updateable query". Another google search found that a similar problem was solved by eliminating the "IMEX=1;".  I removed that from my path and it solved my problem!  I suppose the mapped path and removing IMEX=1; was what this problem needed.

Comment: Ok, so having a mapping drive and trying to use the unc name was throwing it for a loop.  Well, one day this post will help someone.

Comment: this was a little weird not knowing why things worked. But you are so right about leaving a solution for future coders.  I've visited this site many times and it has saved me!